# How to get a specific line with fgets() or fgetss()

Tags: php, html, file

I want to know how I would read a specific line (or even specific character) with `fgets()` or `fgetss()`.

In example;
data.txt-

```
this is data 1
this is data 2
this is data 3
```

How would I read only data 2?

If it's possible, that is.
Also, how can I only read the last line? Like if I were to use `a+` to write at the end of the file, it'd be the newest content.

Another question:
Is it possible to read through the whole file and check if something exists? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you know _exactly_ what the file looks like (and it's consistent and reproducible), you won't be able to. The only way to do this would be to `fseek` to the point in the file that starts the line you want. But again, without knowing the exact data length before that, anything you put there is just a guess. Just read the file line-by-line, using `fgets`, until you get to the line you need.

Comment: @Colin Morelli  Yeah, that's what I thought. Is there any way I could check the whole file if something exists?

Comment: You could use `file_get_contents`, but then you have to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: Would it be a good alternative to databases?

Answer (score 0):

For text file:

```
$fileName = 'file.txt';
$file = new \SplFileObject($fileName);
$file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$seek = 1;
$file->seek($seek);

$line = $file->fgets();
```

In `$line` variable has second line from file.

Comment: Could you please explain this to me? I don't really understand that.   
PS. I'm a PHP noob.

Comment: look here: [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/class.splfileobject.php), look for methods: `seek` and `fgets`. `seek` method sets the pointer at the beginning of the line, `fgets` returns this line.